# Is it possible to add cursors on a click?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a big fan of multicursor mode in Android Studio and use Cmd+G for multi select and alt + drag with mouse for block select a lot. Sometimes, I want to enter multi cursor mode when the text doesn't match/ line up between lines.

Is it possible to click with the mouse in different places and add a new cursor on each click? I believe sublime has something similar although it's been a while since I've used it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Alt + Shift + Click

Comment: Thanks a lot, couldn't find this anywhere when searching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left mouse button click</kbd> to place multiple cursors. You can redefine the mouse shortcut by locating the `Editor Actions | Add or Remove Caret` action in `Settings | Keymap`.

Comment: Afraid it was the shift I was missing as @Leo says

Comment: The default is with the Shift.